# Task.WaitAll hangs in webapi call

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api, async-await

Calling below webapi " Test " from client side (AngularJS). It executes Line1, Line2 and Line3 but it hangs at Line3 and never moved to Line4 and the same Line1, Line2 and Line3 executes fine if executed in unit test of unit test project. Can anyone help whats going wrong here?

```
    [Route("Test")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IHttpActionResult Test(string input)
    {

        var taskA = Dump(a, b); //Line1
        var taskB = Dump(c, d); //Line2
        Task.WaitAll(taskA, taskB); //Line3

        Line4;
        Line5;
        Line6;

        Ok(success);

    }
```

Dump Method:

```
     public async Task Dump(string x, string y)
    {
        await Task.Run(() => methodToDump(x, y));
    }
```

Comment: Mark the method `async` and use `await Task.WhenAll(taskA, taskB);` You'll also need to change the return type to `Task<IHttpActionResult>` or other async equivalent.

Comment: `[Route("Test")]
    [HttpGet]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Test(string input)
    {

        var taskA = Dump(a, b); //Line1
        var taskB = Dump(c, d); //Line2
        await Task.WhenAll(taskA, taskB); //Line3

        Line4;
        Line5;
        Line6;

        Ok(success);

    }`

Comment: It gives the same result. hangs at Line3. I would like to execute Line4 only when tasks started in Line1 and Line2 are finished

Comment: Using `await` your method will not _hang_ at line 3 it will return control to the caller and only execute the following lines after all tasks in the `WhenAll` have completed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the api method to be async and return a Task.

Implement it like this

```
[Route("Test")]
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Test(string input)
{

    var taskA = Dump(a, b); //Line1
    var taskB = Dump(c, d); //Line2
    await Task.WhenAll(taskA, taskB); //Line3

    Line4;
    Line5;
    Line6;

    Ok(success);
}
```

Comment: `WaitAll` is still blocking, swap it out for `WhenAll`

Comment: @JSteward Ok, thanks. Didn't know that. Please edit my answer and you get credit for it.

Comment: Thanks, it worked with WhenAll. I was referring older file earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You also need to change you Dump function to

```
public async Task Dump(string x, string y)
{
    await Task.Run(() => methodToDump(x, y)).ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

There is no code after await, so there is no need to force continuation on the captured SynchronizationContext